# Module not found in snotify

Tags: angular

Trying to import the styling part but it only returns an error. Please see my code below:

Link: https://artemsky.github.io/ng-snotify/documentation/essentials/styling.html

**Code**

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/ng-snotify/styles/material.css",
   "src/styles.css"
]
```

**Error**

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve /node_modules/ng-snotify/styles/material.css

I also tried to use the `.scss` extension since it is exists inside the module but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is your ```angular.json``` file in the same directory where the ```node_modules``` folder is?

Comment: @nullptr.t Nope. The `angular.json` is in the root directory same as `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I just changed to this code:

```
"node_modules/ng-snotify/styles/material.scss"
```

so, I removed `../` and changed from `.css` to `.scss`